# jQuery select elements from one class to another class. All on the same level

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following table structure:

```
…
<tr class="title"><td>Title 1</td></tr>
<tr class="product"><td>Product</td></tr>
<tr class="product"><td>Product</td></tr>
<tr class="product"><td>Product</td></tr>
<tr class="product"><td>Product</td></tr>
<tr class="title"><td>Title 2</td></tr>
<tr class="product"><td>Product</td></tr>
<tr class="product"><td>Product</td></tr>
<tr class="product"><td>Product</td></tr>
<tr class="product"><td>Product</td></tr>
<tr class="product"><td>Product</td></tr>
<tr class="product"><td>Product</td></tr>
<tr class="title"><td>Title 3</td></tr>
<tr class="product"><td>Product</td></tr>
<tr class="product"><td>Product</td></tr>
<tr class="product"><td>Product</td></tr>
…
```

When I click on the title class I would like to target the elements with the class product until the next title class.

Something like this:

```
$(".title").click(function() {

    // get all product classes until the next title
    var target = $(this).[INSERT CODE HERE]

    $(this).toggleClass('show_hide');

    // toggle the content
    $(target).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Because it's all in the same table I cannot use children.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.nextUntil('.title')` to target all the `.product` rows like:

```js
$(".title").click(function() {
   $(this).nextUntil('.title').toggle()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="title">
    <td>Title 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product">
    <td>Product</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product">
    <td>Product</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product">
    <td>Product</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product">
    <td>Product</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="title">
    <td>Title 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product">
    <td>Product</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product">
    <td>Product</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product">
    <td>Product</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product">
    <td>Product</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product">
    <td>Product</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product">
    <td>Product</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="title">
    <td>Title 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product">
    <td>Product</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product">
    <td>Product</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product">
    <td>Product</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).nextUntil('.title').slideToggle("slow");`

Comment: Consider adding some context to your answer to help others understand how you solved the problem.